# How to `reify` a value class definition in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm attempting to `reify` the definition of an implicit value (extension method) class, and am getting the error `value class may not be a local class` when I do so:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val reifiedImplicitValueClass = reify {
  implicit class RicherDouble(val value: Double) extends AnyVal {
    def times(that: Double): Double = value * that
  }
}

error: value class may not be a local class
         implicit class RicherDouble(val value: Double) extends AnyVal {
                        ^
```

If I make it a regular implicit class by taking off the the `extends AnyVal`, it works fine:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val reifiedImplicitClass = reify {
  implicit class RicherDouble(val value: Double)  {
    def times(that: Double): Double = value * that
  }
}

reifiedImplicitClass: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] =
Expr[Unit]({
  implicit class RicherDouble extends AnyRef {
     val value: Double = _;
    def (value: Double) = {
      super.();
      ()
    };
    def times(that: Double): Double = RicherDouble.this.value.$times(that)
  };
  implicit  def RicherDouble(value: Double): RicherDouble = new RicherDouble(value);
  ()
})
```

Is reification of value classes via the reflection API possible? If so, how should my definition be modified?

I'm using Scala 2.11.6.